# Discord Bot unable to send messages

Tags: java, discord, bots

I'm developing a discord bot, but I'm having some problems that I've never had. My discord bot is unable to send messages. The bot doesn't contain any deprecated methods. Here is the code:

Main:

```
private Main() throws LoginException {
    final JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("My.Token.Here", GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntent.GUILD_EMOJIS, GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES).build();

    CommandClientBuilder builder = new CommandClientBuilder();
    builder.setOwnerId("778564522046128148");
    builder.setActivity(Activity.watching("es bueda fixe!"));

    CommandClient client = builder.build();

    jda.addEventListener(client);
    jda.addEventListener(new JoinLeave());
    jda.addEventListener(new TestCommand());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException{
    long enable = System.currentTimeMillis();
    new Main();
    System.out.println("Bot enabled in: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - enable) + "ms!");
}
```

TestCommand (to test if the bot works):

```
public class TestCommand extends ListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e){
    System.out.println("hefdfs");
    if(e.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("!test")){
        e.getChannel().sendMessage("test").queue();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint at `e.getChannel().sendMessage("test").queue();` to see if the line is reached?

Comment: I've had a quick look at the API and if the line is reached you should use the alternative `queue` method with two parameters to see if the call returns an error: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queue(java.util.function.Consumer,java.util.function.Consumer)

Comment: No. It doesn't reach there when I run the command

Comment: Then either a `GuildMessageReceivedEvent` never occurs, or `e.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("!test")` never matches

Comment: Yea but i've seen videos and everyone does this

Comment: And i run the exact command and nothing happens

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you need to check whether `GuildMessageReceivedEvent` fires (breakpoint at start of listener method), and if so: what the actual value of `e.getMessage().getContentRaw()` is so you can manually verify if it matches `"!test"`, such as by introducing an intermediate variable and inspecting it by placing a breakpoint on your if-statement

Answer (score 1):

You disabled the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent. Add it to your list of intents when calling `createDefault`:

```java
EnumSet<GatewayIntent> intents = EnumSet.of(
  GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, // for member join/remove events and cache
  GatewayIntent.GUILD_EMOJIS, // for Guild#getEmotes (not very useful)
  GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, // for member voice states
  GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES // for message received event
);
JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("My.Token.Here", intents)
                    .addEventListeners(new TestCommand(), new JoinCommand(), client)
                    .build();
```

Read up [Gateway Intents and Member Caching](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy)

Comment: OMG THANKS YOU ARE THE BEST THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add **`GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES`**, you should add it